# How to convert between uint256[] and uint256[x]

Tags: solidity, arrays, memory, data-types, uint256

Basically, I want to call a function `myfunct(uint256[] memory)` but I have a `uint256[13]`

I have the uint256[13] because I want to temporarily store uint256s in a function, and save memory--not do storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you change the way you built your `uint256[13]` to use `uint256[] memory _value = new uint256[](13);` instead. Then you should be able to use `myFunc(_value)`.

If your array does not always contain 13 elements, you can replace `13` with a variable, like so:

```
uint256 _n = 3;
uint256[] memory _value = new uint256[](_n);
// populate your array
```